# Dynamic Environment Variable in KSH

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I have to write a script in KSH which defines and uses a dynamic environment variable.

It should read a file in following format

```
 DEV  server_name  DEV_Server
 QA   server_name  QA_Server
 PROD server_name  PROD_Server
```

So if the script is to be executed in DEV, it will be called as follows :

```
     Invocation            Value of server_name
 **script.sh DEV**               DEV_Server
 **script.sh QA**                QA_Server
```

Any clues as to how to implement dynamic variables in KSH ?

Comment: Which implementation of ksh, specifically? If it's ksh93, that's where bash got its `namevar` feature from.

Comment: How do I find out implementation of ksh ?

Comment: That said, a good question factors out everything unrelated to the issue you're having -- if you don't know how to read a file, that should be a *separate* question.

Comment: Well, to start with, how did you install ksh? Or which OS are you using? If you're using the one that came with MacOS, we know it's ksh93. If it came with Linux, it could be real David Korn ksh, or it could be one of the many awful clones. Your package manager should know.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of input and output? I don't quite understand what you want to have happen.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Yes it is KSH93. I know how to read a file but that will not dynamically define a variable

Comment: @JohnKugelman - if I invoke **script.sh DEV**, it should define a variable **server_name** and assign value DEV_Server to it

Comment: Umm. `script.sh DEV` can't change variables in the calling shell at all, directly, indirectly or otherwise. It would have to be `source script.sh DEV`. Or define a function and do the assignment there.

Comment: (Also, using a name ending in `.sh` for a ksh-only script is not great form; best practice is to use `foo.ksh` for things that can only be successfully sourced by ksh, `foo.bash` for things that can only be successfully sourced by bash, `.sh` for a script intended to be sourced and compatible with all POSIX-compliant shells, and no extension at all for scripts that are supposed to be run as executables rather than sourced at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ksh93v or newer, you can use `typeset -n` to make a name refer to a different, dynamically-defined variable:

```
# recommended syntax for ksh but not bash; in ksh, makes all variables local by default
# does not have that effect in bash, and is best avoided there.
function indirect_assign { nameref _dest=$1; _dest=$2; }

while read -r env_name var_name var_value; do
  [[ $env_name = "$1" ]] || continue
  indirect_assign "$var_name" "$var_value"
  export "$var_name"
done
```

Note that this code will need to be sourced (or invoked as a function body) to have any effect on the calling shell.

Comment: On rereading the question, just now saw that you were specifying dynamic *environment variables*, not just dynamic shell variables. Need an explicit `export` to accomplish that; edited appropriately.

Comment: how do I call this indirect_assign ?

Comment: The call in the code, `indirect_assign "$var_name" "$var_value"`, should serve as a demonstration. If you've defined the function in your interactive shell, you can similarly run `indirect_assign "my_var" "my value"`.